# Will EF support more policies for properties updates after insert or update?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Now EF updates properties of inserted entities which have `Identity` or `Computed` [DatabaseGeneratedOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx).

In some cases we need to explicitly tell EF which properties must be read back after insert. (yes, they are updated by triggers)

I try to follow the news about upcoming EF features of, but could miss something.
The most relevant discussion concerning triggers support is this [one](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1441), yet there is no clue about extending the logic of reading back properties after insert or update.

Comment: it seems that there is an open issue about that https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/122

Comment: Is it an acceptable solution ? https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties.html

Comment: Interesting, thank you. But still not clear whether value is read back.

Comment: I think if you annotate the property with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)].` Ef will try to get the new value after insertiion or deletion

Comment: Btw, is expression inside `HasDefaultValueSql` limited to the one you write when declaring default value for the column of the table being created (DDL)?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the question

Comment: Can it be a complex select expression, can it reference properties of the inserted updated entity?

Comment: Why do you need a trigger ? May be you can write a store procedure to insert the data and map the store procedure to the EF model ?

Comment: This will certainly work, but the more EF allows to do without putting logic in DB, the better it is. Actually, the scenario is quite simple. We need to have an instance tag for a number of records. So this number should be generated only once for the first record in the sequence.